# Run commands after opening cmd remotely in Java

Tags: java, shell, sockets, cmd

I was doing some practices to speed up my development in Java sockets, that is why I try to create a remote shell, it works correctly, but the problem comes when I want to execute more than one command once the cmd is executed since it freezes

Server code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class RemoteShell {

    private int port;
    private String commandStr = "cmd";
    private Socket socket;

    public RemoteShell(String [] args) {
        try {
            port = 2222;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid port");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void startServer() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            socket = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public InputStream inputStream() {
        try {
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            return input;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public OutputStream outputStream() {
        try {
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            return output;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getCommand() {
        return commandStr;
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {

        RemoteShell shell = new RemoteShell(args);
        shell.startServer();

        // Read from client
        InputStream input = shell.inputStream();
        // Write output to client
        OutputStream output = shell.outputStream();

        try{
            Process command = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shell.getCommand());
            // Reading output from Process
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(command.getInputStream()));
            // Write data to the Process
            OutputStream commandStream = command.getOutputStream();
            final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                            new OutputStreamWriter(commandStream));


            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    try {
                        int bytesRead;
                        while (command.isAlive() &&
                                ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1))
                        {
                            buffer[bytesRead] = '\n';
                            if (command.isAlive()) {
                                writer.write(new String(buffer));
                                writer.flush();
                                // Sleep to make the command exit
                                // in case 'exit' was written
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line += "\n";
                output.write(line.getBytes());
            }
            command.waitFor();
            thread.join();
            System.out.println("program exit");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 2222;
 
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {
            BufferedReader us = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
            writer.println(us.readLine());
            //writer.println("ipconfig");
            
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
 
            String line;
 
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
 
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
 
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: I don't want to execute more than one command in a launch Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");
if not what I want is to open it and send as many commands as desired by the user

Excuse my English, thank you.

Comment: Running a typical program that uses stdin consumes _all_ of stdin, continuing until the socket is closed. How do you expect to receive another problem to run over the same socket?

Comment: The typical answer to this is to make your wire protocol complex enough to do multiplexing, or at least slice chunks off to give to your programs instead of connecting them to the socket directly.

Comment: I did not understand him well, if not, how do the remote administration programs RAT (trojans) do it?

Comment: So following this procedure, it is impossible? Could you give me some reference on how I should continue? I would really appreciate it, I look forward to your response

Comment: `buffer[bytesRead] = '\n';` is not correct, and `new String(buffer)` is not correct.  If your read did not fill the entire buffer, you must not send the entire buffer.  You probably want `writer.write(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead) + "\n");`.

Comment: I already told you, the sophisticated approaches do multiplexing -- that also lets them run multiple commands at the same time over the same socket. Take a look at how ssh works for an example.

Comment: A very cheap and easy take on multiplexing would just be to break things down into packets with the length (and the identity of which command it's to or from, and which socket on that command it's supposed to be attached to) in the header of each, with a packet type that tells when a channel has been closed.

Comment: @VGR - It still doesn't work making the changes you mention

Comment: @Charles Duffy -  I think I more or less understand the paradigm for an "efficient" response. But really it would be enough for me if it worked, is my approach wrong? Why don't I get the data, why do I miss a line ending?